# How to create grid from 2 separate images of latitude and longitude

Tags: imagery, latitude-longitude, grids-graticules, matlab

I have two separate images of latitude and longitude, and want to create a grid from them so I can assign it to my Non-Geo referenced file... How can I create it, particularly in Matlab... But other help will be useful...

Comment: What do you mean by ` separate images of latitude and longitude`?

Comment: In some rare cases, satellites (or modelling outputs) comes with the georeferencing in separate layers / images, where one image contains latitude values, another image contains longtitude and one or more additional images exist with data in them. The question refers to creating a single georeferenced layer from these lat / lon images and the data layer. I unfortunately can't help with the MapLab.

Comment: I just need an idea how to do that, not specifically with matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution, but two ideas:

1) You could create a list of GroundControlPoints (GCPs) with the lat and long coordinates and the numbers of column and row of the images. Loop through the lat-and long-images and select those values for ever (umpteen) pixel. Then you can use this list of CGPs to georectify/warp your image "image to map".

2) You can create a textfile with the lat- and long-coordinates and the value of the image without geoinformation. Then you can project the points in the list and interpolate/rasterize it to regain a raster.

Comment: Well your ideas are good, now i need to figure it out how to do in Matlab...

Comment: I've only done it in IDL/ENVI and partly in R, so I can't help with Matlab. Why don't you start programming and post a new question, when you a have a specific problem?